# Cant HttpWebRequest in Azure via Hangfire

Tags: c#, azure, umbraco, umbraco7, hangfire

I have a code that run a hangfire background job. Now the job calls a class that in turn this class function will perform a HttpWebRequest to my own UmbracoApiController. Now it's working in my local but somehow when I trigger my hangfire in Azure I'm getting an error

[image]

Correct me if I'm wrong but somehow I think Azure does not allow performing a HttpWebRequest in the background job like Hangfire? or am I just missing a configuration to allow this action? if so where can I find this settings that will allow my jobs to perform HttpWebRequest?

Below is my code that calls my API within the same apps and domain

```
public string TestApi()
{
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Background:Test"]);
        // If required by the server, set the credentials.

        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

        return "Yes " + response;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to find it as I was not the one to setup the server. Can you perhaps tell me where to look?

Comment: No there are no firewalls or it's not behind any company proxies